# Gitlab CI build not triggered on push to ssh remote

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab-ci

We have gitlab ci currently setup (supposedly) to trigger a build whenever anything is pushed to remote. However, I have discovered that if someone pushes to an ssh remote (eg: git@gitlab.com:Project.git) the build is not triggered. If they push to an https remote (eg: https://gitlab.com/Project.git), the build is triggered fine. Any thoughts as to what our problem might be? Our .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

run_project1_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - set -xe
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - apt-get update -yqqq
    - apt-get install -y xvfb google-chrome-stable
    - npm i -g npm@3.7.5 && npm i -g gulp@3.9.1 && npm i -g typings@1.3.1
    - cd project1
    - npm i
    - typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune
    - Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16 &
    - export DISPLAY=:1.0
    - npm test

run_project2_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm i -g npm@3.7.5 && npm i -g typings@1.3.1 && npm i -g jasmine
    - cd project2
    - npm i
    - npm test

deploy_to_docker:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://REMOTE_IP:2375"
    - docker-compose up -d --build
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HTTPS works, but SSH does not, then the problem is in Gitlab, not in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Look into logs and search for errors, run [`gitlab-rake gitlab:check`](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/maintenance/README.html#invoking-rake-tasks) to see whether everything is ok. It sounds like gitlab-shell (its connection to Gitlab) does not work properly.

If everything looks fine, file a bug report at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues.

Comment: There was an issue with our Gitlab instance's upload sources which, when fixed, looks like it resolved our problem. Thanks!